# Move to another ViewController after http response callback

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a swift newbie.

I want to move to another new ViewController after http response callback.

I tried to..

---

1. with segue or delegate protocol

   When I created a segue on storyboard, (with ctrl button and drag)

   moving to another ViewController is faster than http response callback.

   so response data is not shown on the new ViewController

---

2. with instantiateViewController() and present() function

   Error with "NO on non-main thread"

---

```
class RequestViewController: UIViewController {

    ...


    @IBAction func requestButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {

        http.post("/v1/request", jsonBody) { (response) -> () in

            print(response)

            // I want to move to another ViewController with response here
        }
    }
}
```

Any solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use option 2 but perform it on the main queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@IBAction func requestButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {

    http.post("/v1/request", jsonBody) { (response) -> () in

        DispatchQueue.main.async { 
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToOtherVC", sender: self)      
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
@IBAction func requestButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {

    http.post("/v1/request", jsonBody) { (response) -> () in

        DispatchQueue.main.async { 
            let vc = OtherViewController()
            self.present(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

btw, I can recommend use `[weak self]` in closures, for avoid memory leak, you can read more at [Swift Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Comment: I used your second option and it works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use DispatchQueue.main.async in order to perform UI changes since UI changes are always to be done from main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //Your code to present or push to next View Controller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"NO on non-main thread" error appeared because you are updating your UI from background thread. You need to change UI from main thread.

```
  @IBAction func requestButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
         http.post("/v1/request", jsonBody) {[weak self](response) -> () in
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 let nextVC = NextViewController() 
                 self?.present(nextVC,animated: true)
               }
            }
        }
```